# Add or remove rows in destination array to exactly fit source data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this subroutine to copy-paste data between two opened workbooks ...

```
Sub Import_Recap()

Dim wb As Workbook, x As String
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then x = wb.Name
Next wb
    If x = "" Then
        MsgBox "Open the source workbook first !!!", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Set wsSource = Workbooks(x).Sheets(1)
  Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)

wsDest.Activate
wsDest.ShowAllData
wsSource.Rows("1:17").Delete Shift:=xlUp
wsSource.Range("B:B,C:C,G:G,J:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

y = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("A1"), wsSource.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
z = wsDest.Range(Range("A10"), Range("A10").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
j = y - z

wsDest.Range(Range("A10"), Range("A10").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).ClearContents

If j > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To j
        wsDest.Rows("15:15").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next i
ElseIf j < 0 Then
    For i = 1 To j * -1
        wsDest.Rows("15:15").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Next i
End If

returnvalue = MsgBox("Do you want to import data from: " & x & ".", vbYesNo)
If returnvalue = 6 Then ''YES button clicked
    wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy wsDest.Range("A10")
ElseIf returnvalue = 7 Then ''NO button clicked
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

The two arrays have the same columns, only the number of rows in the source workbook is different every time. There is also other data below the currently used range in destination workbook and a specific format, which I want to keep.
I was thinking of comparing the used rows count in source and destination current regions and then using Do while loop to insert or delete rows somewhere in the middle of destination until equals.
Is there a nicer way of doing something like this?

Edit: I've updated the code above with a solution. I've used two for loops instead of do while/until ... still feels kinda weird doing it that way, but at least it's working.

Comment: Side note, but you need `wsDest.` in front of the two instances of `Range("A10")` in the line `wsDest.Range(Range("A10"), Range("A10").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).ClearContents`

Comment: Actually, because this is happening after wsDest is activated, I don't need to reference it in the two rows below ... it's there only for a reminder.

Comment: Better practice would be to fully qualify your `Range` calls and get rid of the `wsDest.Activate`.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I just need to go there anyway to apply some filters and print the thing.

Comment: Describe more accurately what the code is supposed to do. "*to insert or delete rows somewhere in the middle of destination until equals*" could mean a lot of things. Adding a screenshot of your data may do wonders. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72365845/edit) at any time.

Comment: I will try, thanks! What I mean by that is until the number of used rows in source is equals to the number of formatted rows in destination.